# What does this symbol ( <> ) mean?

Tags: math

This is the first time I see it.

This is his context :

```
Edges (x,y) and (y,x) for each x <> y should appear consecutively in the output file.
```

Comment: In general context that means not equals to. In SQL, Python etc., you can see this operator.

Comment: it's too broad. Math doesn't use it. Some programming languages use it like VB and Pascal. Excel also uses it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<>` symbol means "not equal to": $\neq%$. The symbol is effectively stating "for each x greater than or less than y".

Can also be seen in various other languages as `!=`.